# 'DB2INSTANCE environment variable is not set' error while Rational Asset Analyzer V6. 1 tool installation

Tags: windows, db2

I am getting an error while doing RAA V6.1 tool installation as `The installation unable to verify username/password because the DB2INSTANCE environment variable is not set`.

I have installed DB2 10 windows on my system.

Any one faced similar issue before?

Comment: Did you set the environment variables as described in the installation process?

Comment: Hi Michael , I can see Db2PATH variable is set correctly to C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\SQLLIBalso I can see DB2INSTACE = DB2

Comment: I don't have DB2 installation guide with me

Answer (score 1):

I just faced this problem and no amount of solutions provided by IBM support site would work.
It got resolved when I uninstalled and reinstalled DB2 server on c:\IBM\SQLLIB.
Earlier it was installed on default path c:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB.
I think the space in the directory was messing few things up.